# How variables are getting assigned in this code?

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, tree

I was writing code for checking binary tree balanced or not and came across below snippet, this works perfectly fine but I am failing to understand when and how values for 'lh' and 'lr' variables are getting assigned in below code. These are out vairables and this is c# code.

```
public bool IsBalanced(Node node,out int height, bool isleft)
{
    int lh, lr;
    if(node==null)
    {
        height = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("NULL");
        return true;
    }
    if (isleft)
        Console.WriteLine("L " + node.data);
    else if(!isleft)
        Console.WriteLine("R " + node.data);
    bool balanced = IsBalanced(node.left,out lh, true) & IsBalanced(node.right,out lr,false);
    height = Math.Max(lh, lr) + 1;
    Console.WriteLine("lh :" + lh + " and " + "lr :" +lr);
    Console.WriteLine("height :" + height);
    return balanced & (Math.Abs(lh - lr) <=1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that assigning them is `IsBalanced`.
As you will notice the following line:

```
IsBalanced(node.left,out lh, true)
IsBalanced(node.right,out lr,false)
```

You will see in this case, that `out lh` is passed to the method. This passes the reference of **lh** to the method, which allowing it to assign a value to the variable.

The actual assignments are: `(out int height)`

```
height = 0;
height = Math.Max(lh, lr) + 1;
```

Comment: IsBalanced is recursive calls ... and in recursion there is no assignment statement

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx), `out` is used to signalize a method, that it **must** assign a value to a parameter, which can be used by the caller-method. I.e. `IsBalanced(node.left,out lh, true)` calls `IsBalanced` with`lh` as parameter, that will be overwritten by the method. Afterwards the caller-method can use the value that was assigned in `IsBalanced`.

So `IsBalanced` basically calculates the height of the subtree with the parameter-node as root and updates the `height`-method parameter with that value.